# Is calling service from controller a violation of MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, model-view-controller, n-tier-architecture

I have seen many code references online they use services directly in the Controller.

```
public class PersonController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Index(int personId)
   {
       Person personDataModel = null;
       using(var service = new Personservice())
       {
          personDataModel = service.GetPerson(personId);
       }

       var personVM = MapPersonDataModelToViewModel(personDataModel);

       return View("Index",personVM);
   }
}
```

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381412(v=vs.108).aspx), ***Controllers*** are the components that handle user interaction, work with the ***model***, and ultimately select a ***view*** to render that displays UI.

Where is the mention of **Service**? 
I know people talking about Service layer pattern or SOA architecture. But still is this a ***violation***. A ***violation for convenience***?

*For some reason, if I want to do away with services. Then I'll end up changing the controller. And have to build my model. **Instead I'm suppose to change only the Model.***

I feel Model should have the intelligence to serve the request from Controller either by calling external service or by itself.

```
public class PersonController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Index(int personId)
   {
       var personVM = PersonModel.GetPerson(personId);

       return View("Index",personVM);
   }
}

public class PersonModel
{
   public PersonVM GetPerson(int personId)
   {
      Person personDataModel = null;
       //Can either do this
       using(var service = new Personservice())
       {
          personDataModel = service.GetPerson(personId);
       }

       //Or can do this
       personDataModel = GetPersonDataModel(personId);

      var personVM = MapPersonDataModelToViewModel(personDataModel);

      return personVM;
   }
}
```

I know PersonModel needs re-factoring but that's not the point.

***UPDATE:***

***When I mean Model, I'm not referring to MODEL(class with properties) that we pass to View. I mean the classes in the folder Model.***

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381412(v=vs.108).aspx), Models: Model objects are the parts of the application that implement the logic for the application's data domain. Often, model objects retrieve and store model state in a database.

I assume from above that class objects in the folder Model should have the logic to conduct CRUD operations.

Am I missing something. Please share your valuable thoughts.

Comment: It depends in many moving parts. If you follow DDD you will have different types of services, some of them  are ok if you use them in controllers, others make more sense calling them from object persistence layers or view models as in your case. Apart of that,  it depends also from the scope of your system, I would not dare to build services and adding layers for simple application just to follow the rules. At the end it is a matter of personal taste... just a thought.

Comment: I'm talking specifically about services for CRUD operations.

Comment: First off, your article is a little dated(MVC4.). That being said, MVC is more like M-MV-V-C where MV is used.  Check out this page: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel

Answer (score 2):

No. In fact, it's [advocated](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/never-mind-the-controller,-here-is-the-orchestrator/) as a way to keep controllers nice and slim.

Comment: In the link you provided, Orchestrator object used in the controller is similar to the PersonModel I mentioned. My point is talking to external services is the responsibility of Model not the controller. Controller has to pass the command to the Model for crud. Model in turn may use external services.

Comment: I view the term 'model' in the most abstract way when I approach MVC, and MVP for that matter. I view an external service, an orchestrator, a repository and anything else that the controller needs to get the work done, as the 'model'. Considering the 'model' as a single thing is one of the biggest misconceptions the documentation on these patterns perpetuate, IMHO.

Comment: I see what you saying but then the orchestrator or repository shouldn't be part of the folder Model. If not what is the significance of having the folder Models in asp.net mvc project.

Comment: Or if they are part of folder Models do you see any concern?

Comment: I only have view model classes in my Models folder.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use Repositories with the UnitOfWork pattern.  Here is a great article for this: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

I have been doing this for several years, and I find it much easier to manage the application.  For some models, I create a base class and then create a generic repository that accepts the base class.

Comment: Sorry, my question is not regarding best practice for building data access. As per mvc, controller should pass the command to Model for crud operations. Model might use repository pattern or something else for executing the command. My question is , Is it not a violation for a controller to communicate with a service rather than a model?

Comment: No, its not a violation.  You also have to take into account viewmodels vs data models.  A service works well by allowing access to the same data model (like account) using different viewmodels (like registrationViewModel.)

Answer (score 0):

Controllers: Classes that handle incoming browser requests, retrieve model data, and then specify view templates that return a response to the browser.

If you find your controller has too much code in it (or, more importantly, that it has business logic in it), then what you need is an application facade layer that sits between your controller and your service layer, co-ordinates your services and provides a simpler interface for your controllers.

Alternatively, if the code you're trying to move is presentation-layer logic (such as model validation, construction of view models, processing of form values, mapping of view models to service-layer entities etc.), then it does belong in your controller - even if there are more than a couple of lines of it. You can still simplify things by breaking it up into helpers if it's beneficial to do so, but don't do this just because someone told you that your controller actions shouldn't have more than five lines of code in them.

Another option is to create an extension method for your servide and calling in the controller like this

Extension method for IStudentService:

```
public static class StudentServiceExtensions
{
public static StudentViewModel CreateViewModel(
    this IStudentService service,
    int id)
{
    var e = service.GetStudentDetails(id);
    var vm = ConvertStudentToViewModel(e);
    return vm;
}
}
```

which you'd then call in your controller like so:

```
 var viewModel = this.StudentService.CreateViewModel(id);
```